# Truncate e-mail text string at the @ portion in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, text, truncate

I have a situation in ASP.NET C# wherein for example I have the email address **hello@gmail.com** but I need to have the **@gmail.com** portion removed for all email input. Please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
email = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf('@'));
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I've explored substring and it worked. :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [MailAddress Class (System.Net.Mail)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx):

```
string mailAddress = "hello@gmail.com";
var mail = new MailAddress(mailAddress);

string userName = mail.User; // hello
string host = mail.Host; // gmail.com
string address = mail.Address; // hello@gmail.com
```

In the case of wrong e-mail address (eg. lack of at sign or more than one) you have to catch [FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx), for example:

```
string mailAddress = "hello@gmail@";
var mail = new MailAddress(mailAddress); // error: FormatException
```

If you don't want to verify e-mail address, you can use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method from string:

```
string mailAddress = "hello@gmail.com";
char atSign = '@';
string user = mailAddress.Split(atSign)[0]; // hello
string host = mailAddress.Split(atSign)[1]; // gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
new MailAddress(someString).User
```

If the email address is invalid, this will throw an exception.

If you also need to validate the email address, you should write `new MaillAddress(someString)` inside of a `catch` block; this is the best way to validate email addresses in .Net.